# Is there another word for "personal" in "personal value"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, adjectives

A friend offers you money for an a necklace, but you refuse to sell because you obtained the necklace from a friend who died.

You now consider that necklace to have "personal" value (value that you can't put a price tag on).

## Question

Is there a better word than "*personal*" that better describes the value of the object?

"Personal" does not express the exact nature of the situation, as it lacks the true attachment to the item (it came from a special person).

Comment: You have an *intimacy or attachment* to it.

Comment: It has sentimental value.

Comment: @Jim Thank you :) If a friend has a bad dream about an object, resulting in them disliking the object IRL, would that also be considered sentimental?

Comment: @VinceEmigh - No. that’s more *superstitious*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The phrase that would describe this exactly is "sentimental value".

[Merriam Webster defines **Sentimental Value**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentimental%20value) as:

> - importance to someone because of a connection with a happy time of life, a special person, etc. *The picture has sentimental value for me.*

This means that there's an emotional and subjective value to it based on memory of past experience rather than any objective value.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Providing links to support your answer is a good practice in this site, as it enhances your answer's credibility.